# How to use Tensorboard with Tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tflearn

I am used tflearn
yet I want to use the tensorboard and its visualization
how can I use it?
how to get the session form tflearn?

for example for this example (Pannous speech_data) https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_speech_recognition_demo/blob/master/demo.py

Answer (score 4):

TFLearn supports a verbose level to automatically manage summaries. Setting it to `3` will enable visualization.

Set,

```
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=3)
```

You can learn more about it in the [Getting started guide](http://tflearn.org/getting_started/#visualization).

Comment: After adding `tensorboard_verbose=3` Tensorboard says "No dashboards are active for the current data set.". any advice?